# How can I use parts of code with a "3rd party" doing the implementation of an interface?

Tags: c#

To add some information. The 3rd party implementations will adhere to the interface.

Given that the implementation of an interface is "hidden" from me. How can I use the hidden class implementation for my own program?

This is what the interface structure looks like.

```
namespace CompanyName.Integration.Class

public interface ClassInterface{
    //Some methods
}
```

And then in the program I'm writing to implement some stuff:

```
namespace CompanyName.Integration.Class

namespace MyProgram{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            //here is where I want to use the not yet implemented/"hidden" implementation of the interface


        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the class that isn't implemented and that I only know/have access to the interface of?

Because I cannot do something like `new class = new interface`. So how do I solve this problem?

Can I do something like extend the interface or give the class a interface kind of like `List<E>`?

Comment: Who sais there´s only *one* possible implementation for the interface? It´s possible that there are dozens. Your question can´t be solved, you have to know *what* to instantiate* in order to do something with it. The fact that the class implements an interface doesn´t mean anything to what that instance actually *is*. In particular it doesn´t even mean that there *is* a class that implements it, so you may have an interface that does not have *any* implementing class.

Comment: well, for COM interfaces var x = new ISomeComInterface() might or might not actually do what you'd expect ...

Comment: You have to create an instance of the class somewhere to use it anywhere in your code. What you can do is to use the interface as a dependency in on of your methods like that:
`public void DoStuff(ClassInterface classinterface) {}`. Here you have access to all methods defined in the interface

But you have to instantiate the interface at some point.

Comment: depending on what you are coding ... let's say a module extension ...you could use dependency injection ... google: dependency injection, inversion of control, IOC container

Comment: Sounds pretty much like a "plugin system", in which external DLLs add implementations to your provided interfaces. You can instantiate them using reflection, even without knowing their types, if you load the assemblies beforehand.

Comment: What I'm thinking is if this can be solved with generics of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scan the assembly for all types that implement that interface via reflection:

```
var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyInterface))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(x) && type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null);
```

Now you can instantiate your classes. Be aware that `types` may contain multiple types that implement the interface. For simplicity I just chose the very first:

```
var newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(types.First());
```

However as noted within the comments it´s even possible that the vendor of the assembly didn´t even provide any class that implement the interface, or that such a type exists in another assembly. Furthermore it´s possible that the class(es) don´t have a default-constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the input HimBromBeere!

I'm getting an error with the `type.IsAssignableFrom(x) `part saying  `type does not exist in the current context`.

I'm not familiar at all with this type of programming so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Gurkang Change to `Where(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(...) & ...)`.